# Realm First User in Static function

Tags: swift, realm

My user info only will have a single record so how do I return just the first record from a static function?

If I add realm.objects(UserInfo.self).first it will give me:

```
Cannot convert return expression of type 'UserInfo?' to return type 'Results<UserInfo>?'
```

my static function to get the user information:

```
static func getUserInfo() -> Results<UserInfo>? {
    do {
        let realm = try Realm()
        var userInfo = realm.objects(UserInfo.self)
        return userInfo
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Swift and Realm are both new to me - so thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of your static function does not match your intention. `Results<UserInfo>?` is a Collection (very similar to an `Array`). If you want the single UserInfo object the return type should be `UserInfo?`:

```
static func getUserInfo() -> UserInfo? {
    do {
        let realm = try Realm()
        return realm.objects(UserInfo.self).first
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. I see the difference. This is my first adventure with Realm.  Thanks!